# Difference between HttpStatus.OK and HttpStatus.ACCEPTED

Tags: spring, api, rest

I am about to implement a REST api. I want to know what's the difference between `HttpStatus.OK` and `HttpStatus.ACCEPTED`:

```
return new ResponseEntity<User>(u, HttpStatus.OK));
```

And

```
return new ResponseEntity<User>(u, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per Spring documentation  given on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html)

> **HttpStatus.OK**
>
> 200 Ok means The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request
>
> **HttpStatus.ACCEPTED:**
>
> 202 Accepted. means  The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

for More information on HTTP response Status Code Definitions please visit this [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)